# how to stop read() function?

Tags: sockets, udp

I am writing an UDP client/server programs in C on linux. The thing is that I must add connection check feature. in linux man pages i found example of udp client with this feature( http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html ). It uses write/read functions to check server response. I tried to apply it to my program, and it looks like this:

```
char *test = "test";
nlen = strlen(test) + 1;
if (write(sock, test, nlen) != nlen) {              // socket with the connection
    fprintf(stderr, "partial/failed write\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

nread = read(sock, buf, nlen);
if (nread == -1) {
    perror("Connection");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

the problem is than than i execute program with this bit when server is on, it does nothing except reading input infinite time which it doesn't use too. I tried kill(getpid(), SIGHUP) interrupt, which i found other similar topic here, and shutdown(sock, 1), but nothing seems to work. Could you please tell me a way out how to stop the input read or any other possible option to check if udp server is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use asynchronous reading.

For this you must use the select() function from "sys/socket.h".

The function monitors the socket descriptor for changes without blocking.

You can find the reference for it [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc750/html/lr2/select.htm) or [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) or by typing "man select" in your console.

There is an example [here](http://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/windowsocketwinsock214_18.html) for Windows, but its usage is very similar to UNIX.

Comment: Good suggestion, although this isn't "asynchronous reading", it's synchronous multiplexed reading.

Comment: You probably meant using a timeout here, because `select(2)` also blocks waiting for IO events, so now you have the problem of interrupting that.

Comment: Yep, use "select" with a timeout.

Comment: im not sure if i got it right, but i think it doesnt work with dgram socket. when im describing the socket writefds in client side, select return 1 regardless if server is on or off